# Why does the txid increment?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I  have the below script:

```
select txid_current();
```

the txid displayed is =001

```
begin;
insert into tab values(10,20); insert into values(20,40);
commit;
```

Now when I do :
    select txid_current();

The txid see is :004 
Why is there an increment by 2 i.e  why is there an Increase in txid by 2 shouldn't the increment be just by 1 i.e txid should be 003 shouldn't select txid_current() show 003 ?

Is there a way to display 003 as the current txid()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Transaction](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-transactions.html)**

> PostgreSQL actually treats every SQL statement as being executed
>   within a transaction. If you do not issue a BEGIN command, then each
>   individual statement has an implicit BEGIN and (if successful) COMMIT
>   wrapped around it. A group of statements surrounded by BEGIN and
>   COMMIT is sometimes called a transaction block.

It means when you run `select txid_current();` you're in a transaction and after this run you get new transaction id.

```
begin;
select txid_current(); // 1
end;

begin;
insert into tab values(10,20); insert into values(20,40);
select txid_current(); // 2
commit;

begin;
select txid_current(); // 3
end;
```

Comment: Thanks  for the clarification.I'm actually new to psql hence trying to learn the same.So does it mean even a simple select statement is a single transaction although it doesn't really alter the database ?also what is the difference between select txid_current();  and  select txid_current_snapshot();  ? why does does that show 003 instead of 004 ?

Comment: @MissJ. yes and as I sad every SQL statement :)

Comment: @MissJ. try to play with that. Just run select txid_current(); a few times and look at result

Comment: Yes I do see what you say... I'm new to plsql so tyring to learn the same :) ... what is the difference between select txid_current(); and select txid_current_snapshot(); ? why does does that show 003 instead of 004 ?